# Action View missing Template in RoR 5 when calling instance variable from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax

Trying to render a to-do list with Ajax through Ruby on Rails.
Here is the index.html.erb snippet:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1" id="tasks"><%= render @tasks %></div>
</div>
```

The error raises when render @tasks hits.
The message states "Missing partial tasks/_task "

My controller declares that @tasks = Task.all as follows

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
before_action :all_tasks, only: [:index, :create]
respond_to :html, :js

def index
    @tasks = Task.all
end

def new
    @task = Task.new
end

def create
    @task = Task.create(task_params)
end

private

    def all_tasks
        @tasks = Task.all
    end

    def task_params
        params.require(:task).permit(:description, :deadline)
    end
end
```

Not sure what the issue is in this situation.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's asking for a task partial within your `app/views/tasks` folder.

To use or print `@tasks` you just call use it in your view using Ruby inside your views like `<%= ruby_code %>`

By default, controllers in Rails automatically render views with names that correspond to actions, it means if you use `<%= render @tasks %>`, Rails will try to find for some partial called `tasks` within the parent folder that's printing the current view.

Also I've seen you're assigning twice the value of `@books` in your `index` method, if you're using the `before_action :all_tasks` in your `index` then you don't need to "redeclare" it again.

Try with:

```
# app/views/index.html.erb
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-7 col-md-offset-1" id="tasks">
    <%= @tasks %>
  </div>
</div>

# app/controllers/tasks_controller.rb
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :all_tasks, only: [:index, :create]
  respond_to :html, :js

  def index
  end

  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  def create
    @task = Task.create(task_params)
  end

  private

  def all_tasks
    @tasks = Task.all
  end

  def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:description, :deadline)
  end
end
```